# How to fix "Google Play purchases are not supported in your country" error?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Receiving this error:
"Google Play purchases are not supported in your country"  while trying to pay for a subscription in-app.

This error is happening while in North America. Google Account and card is North American.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by updating Billing version from version 3 to version 4!